# want to transform this javascript nested object to flat object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i have this input array:

```
input = [{
    id: "1",
    object: {
        email: "john@gmail",
        name: "john"
    }
}, {
    id: "2",
    object: {
        email: "john@gmail",
        name: "john"
    }
}]
```

I'd like to transform this such that it no longer as the nested property `object`:

```
output = [{
    id: "1",
    email: "john@gmail",
    name: "john"
}, {
    id: "2",
    email: "john@gmail",
    name: "john"
}]
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use destructuring assignment and then transform the array using `map()` function. Like so:

```
input.map(({id, object}) => ({id, email: object.email, name: object.name}));
```

```js
let input = [{
    id: "1",
    object: {
        email: "john@gmail",
        name: "john"
    }
}, {
    id: "2",
    object: {
        email: "john@gmail",
        name: "john"
    }
}];

let output = input.map(({id, object}) => ({id, email: object.email, name: object.name}));
console.log(output);
```